# Can I change the API url of a third Party API?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, api, web-scraping

I want to request a third party API on Web APP. The API example is **https://api.pinesapsapi.com/request**.

Can I change the URL and build a different URL with any of the external platforms or AWS?

The basic reason of the URL changing is to keep the API Url private with my developers.

Is this possible?

For Example:
**https://api.pinesapsapi.com/request** should look something like  **https://api.xhatdffsdkj.com/request** or any other generic URL

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an AWS service to specifically do this your best best would be using [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/).

Configure a [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html) that uses a single method of `/{proxy+}` and configure it with `HTTP_PROXY`. You can then add a custom domain name to your API Gateway setup and have it proxy to this other other domain.

**Alternatively** you would be looking at using a proxy based solution to forward the requests to the endpoint (such as [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) running on a host such as EC2).

Comment: Is it necessary to add proxy?

Comment: For which solution are you talking about? :). You don't need the EC2 proxy if you use API Gateway

Comment: Is there other platforms to use Custom Url? 

Basically what I want is the when i call the custom Url => then custom url should call the third-party API => Fetch data from there and send it back to me...

There reason behind this is to keep the api base url confidential...

Comment: I am not using their ec2 instance

Comment: You could also use CloudFront but it is a CDN, you'd need to disable any caching and ensure the correct host header is forwarded to the target endpoint.

Comment: Chris Thanks for your help... Would love to know if there is other option instead of AWS?

Comment: I'm sure there are similar services offered by other Cloud providers although I only use AWS so do not know which services these would be :)